# Vaadin/Wildfly Swarm Demo not working

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, demo, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to recreate the Vaadin Wildfly Swarm demo with the version 8 from Vaadin, but it doesn't work!

I'm following the demo as we can find here: https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/vaadin

If we download the source code from this repository and execute, it works.

But if I remove it from this repository, and only add the Vaadin/Wildfly Swarm dependences, it doesn't work.

It will run with no errors, but we cannot hit the http://localhost:8080/

Here is my example removing it from its repository: https://github.com/vepo/vaadin-demo

How can I made the hello world works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may sometimes be hard to see what you need to copy from the parent project, if you are flattening a Maven multi-module project hierarchy, as with the swarm examples project.

I created a [minimal Vaadin + Swarm project](https://github.com/mstahv/swarm-generator-example) without parent projects using the Swarm Generator and by adding needed Vaadin dependencies. Check that out and you can base your project on that. The project also contains vaadin-maven-plugin and [Directory](https://vaadin.com/directory/) maven repository so it is easy to start to use client side add-ons.

BTW. I also created a pull request to update the official Vaadin example to V8.

Comment: My 2 cents are here. I didn't have too much trouble to get Swarm, Vaadin 8 & Cdi to work. I anyway think that CD helpers add on would still need update to work with vaadin 8.3.1, for which reason I couldn't try it. https://github.com/nikkijuk/vaadin-playground/tree/master/vaadin8cdi

Comment: True, I should really find out a moment to update the CDI Helpers for most recent version. Should be quite easy task.

Comment: Thanks. We have one CDI projects stuck at 8.1.6 and it would be nice when they could benefit from changes made to Binder at 8.3